# Can't connect rabbitmq and redis from container to another in same network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq, nest

I'm using a docker-compose file to work with my services and dbs locally, so I prepared a docker-compose file like below

```
version: '3'

networks:
  sosyal:
    driver: bridge
services:
  db:
    container_name: sql
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: 514Emir229
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
      MSSQL_DATABASE: TestDB
    volumes:
      - mssql-data:/var/opt/mssql
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    networks:
      - sosyal

  rabbitmq-docker:
    container_name: rabbitmq-docker
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: guest
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: guest
    volumes:
      - rabbitmq_data:/data
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    networks:
      - sosyal
  redis-docker:
    container_name: redis-docker
    image: redis/redis-stack:latest

    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - sosyal
  sosyal-auth:
    build:
      context: sosyal-auth
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - /Users/emirkutlugun/projects/sosyal-yeni/sosyal-auth/.development.docker.env
    networks:
      - sosyal
    depends_on:
      - db
      - rabbitmq-docker
      - redis-docker
  sosyal-account:
    build:
      context: sosyal-account
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - /Users/emirkutlugun/projects/sosyal-yeni/sosyal-account/.development.docker.env
    networks:
      - sosyal
    depends_on:
      - db
      - rabbitmq-docker
      - redis-docker

  sosyal-gateway:
    build:
      context: sosyal-gateway
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - sosyal-auth
      - sosyal-account
    networks:
      - sosyal


volumes:
  mssql-data:
  rabbitmq_data:
```

after that I changed my connection string for rabbit mq to

```
    const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(AppModule, {
        transport: Transport.RMQ,
        options: {
            urls: [`amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq-docker:5672`],
            queue: 'user_queue',
            queueOptions: {
                durable: false
            },
        },
    })
```

but when I try to connect I get the following error

```
sosyal-account-1  | [Nest] 1  - 02/08/2024, 7:10:43 AM   ERROR [Server] Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5672
```

I really don't understand why it tries to connect to `127.0.0.1:5672` ?

When I check the network, they all are in the same. So how to connect rabbitmq from another container in the same docker-compose ?

**Solution**

i was making a mistake with my dockerfiles in auth-service and account service, they were creating containers based on old dist file that was not changing at all, fixed dockerfiles and they connected to rabbitmq properly.

Comment: "i really don't understand why it tries to connect 127.0.0.1:5672 ?" --- so maybe you haven't changed the connection string in fact? How did you verify the credentials have been changed?

Comment: i changed it's host to rabbitmq-docker for sure and made docker-system prune after this error, still same error.

Comment: Have you checked that your changes are actually in the container?

Comment: how to check this correctly, it currently builds from dockerfile and im running command docker-compose up --build

Comment: Check container logs first. Once you are satisfied that there is no error, you can start investigating the connection error. What do you use? Docker desktop on windows or using linux? Try to `telnet localhost 5672`.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like your application not getting Rabbitmq url you have provided.

```
docker exec -it yourBackendContainerName /bin/sh
```

After that you should try to ping rabbitmq container.

```
  ping rabbitmq-docker
```

if it resolves proper host other that that 127.0.0.1 then probably the issue is in your code

Comment: as you can see my rabbitmq connection url does not contains 127.0.0.1 but it still gives error as that

Comment: it was a dockerfile mistake, i was not updating my containers as it appears, so i modified dockerfiles to fix the error it worked